# PHP $_GET is empty trying first REST requests

Tags: php

trying to get my head around REST, I am following/copying a tutorial. The "$_get" is blank, I noticed that the URL that is being called is blank here is a copy,

```
http://localhost/RestClient/index.php?action=get_user&id=
```

but the href I am clicking looks ok to me.

```
<a href='http://localhost/RestClient/index.php?action=get_user&id='3' alt=user_'3'>Carbonnel</a>
```

here is my code I am new to PHP so figuring it all as I go!!!!

```
<?php
/*** this is the client ***/
if (isset($_GET["action"]) && isset($_GET["id"]) && $_GET["action"] == "get_user") // if the   get  parameter action is get_user and if the id is set, call the api to get the user information
 {
 $user_info = file_get_contents('http://localhost/RestServer/api.php?action=get_user&id=' .  $_GET    ["id"]);
$user_info = json_decode($user_info, true);

// THAT IS VERY QUICK AND DIRTY !!!!!
?>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name: </td><td> <?php echo $user_info["last_name"] ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>First Name: </td><td> <?php echo $user_info["first_name"] ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Age: </td><td> <?php echo $user_info["age"] ?></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <a href="http://localhost/RestClient/index.php?action=get_userlist" >Return to the user list</a>
 <?php
 }
 else // else take the user list
 {
 $user_list = file_get_contents('http://localhost/RestServer/api.php?action=get_user_list');
 $user_list = json_decode($user_list, true);
 // THAT IS VERY QUICK AND DIRTY !!!!!
 ?>
 <ul>
 <?php foreach ($user_list as $user): ?>
  <li>

    <?php echo "<a href='http://localhost/RestClient/index.php?action=get_user&id='".$user ['id']."' alt=user_'".$user['id']."'>"; ?><?php echo $user["name"] . "</a>"; ?>


  </li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
  <?php
 }
?>
```

Comment: This should work: `<a href='http://localhost/RestClient/index.php?action=get_user&id=3 alt=user_3>Carbonnel</a>`

Answer (score 2):

The Link

```
<a href='http://localhost/RestClient/index.php?action=get_user&id='3' alt=user_'3'>Carbonnel</a>
```

is incorrect, it must be:

```
<a href='http://localhost/RestClient/index.php?action=get_user&id=3' alt='user_3'>Carbonnel</a>
```

Watch the changes in ' signs.

In you example `$_GET['id']` must have been always `null`.

Comment: If I copy the link into my code it work correct, how do I append the variables into the string and keep the structure correct?

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely something wrong with you `<a>`.
You are using single quotes for the tag attribute and then for query string parameters too.

Any program having to interpret that will have no idea where the `href=` actually ends.

One solution would be to use double quotes (`"`) for the attribute and single quotes for the value (if you need those at all).

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<?php echo "<a href='http://localhost/RestClient/index.php?action=get_user&id='".$user ['id']."' alt=user_'".$user['id']."'>"; ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo "<a href='http://localhost/RestClient/index.php?action=get_user&id=".$user ['id']." alt=user_".$user['id']."'>"; ?>
```